# Bootstrap modal events not firing on rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="pergunta-modal" >
  ...
</div>
```

And the following modal event:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#pergunta-modal').on 'shown.bs.modal', ->
   $('#tipo_pergunta').change ->
      if $(this).val() is "Resposta aberta"
        $("#alternativas").hide()
      else
        $("#alternativas").show()
```

Problem is, the event does not fire, I tried changing it show, or any other, doesn't work I can't get anything to happen with 'shown.bs.modal' event, I am using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem latest release and rails 4.0.1, testing on chrome 37

EDIT: I managed to solve this by adding the javascript code to the end of the modal partial, since the modal is not yet instantiated at the time the callback is created, as per this question:
[Twitter bootstrap modal event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486728/twitter-bootstrap-modal-event-not-firing)

However, I am still not satisfied code-quality-wise, how can I change this so that the code can sit on the javascript files in the assets folder?

Comment: What is `tipo_pergunta` and `alternativas`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 4 has `turbolinks` enabled by default. This means that de common `document.ready` event gets only fired when there is a full page reload, and therefore your binding to the `shown.bs.modal` event never happens.

I would rewrite your coffescript like this

```
$(document).on 'shown.bs.modal', "#pergunta-modal", ->
    $('#tipo_pergunta').change ->
        if $(this).val() is "Resposta aberta"
            $("#alternativas").hide()
        else
            $("#alternativas").show()
```